# Which one of these sentences is standard English? ["own their homes" or "have their own homes"]

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

Which one of the following sentences is standard English?

> Two-thirds of them have their own homes.
>
> Two-thirds of them own their homes.

Comment: Both sentences are OK, but it's **two-thirds** with an 's'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael Harvey has noted, it should be two-thirds not two-third. Third is plural since their are more than one of them.

With the correction of Two-third to Two-thirds, both are standard English. They are not synonymous though.

The first could mean a number of things depending on the context, including for example:

> that they have a home to live in that they don't share,
>
> that they have a home to live in that they don't own, or
>
> that they have a home that they own.

There may be other ways to interpret that as well.

The second makes clear that their home is owned by them.